# Why does this datetime method fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm using a basic function to obtain Hours, Minutes Seconds.  Everything works if time is less than 24 hours.  I want to get hours even if they are more than 24 not days.

**The folowing example below produces:
00h:00m:00s**

My Test:

```
[TestMethod()]      
public void Test_Hours_Greater_Than_24()
{
   EmployeeSkill target = new EmployeeSkill();  appropriate value
   double sec = 86400;
   string expected = "24h:00m:00s"; 
   string actual;
   actual = target.GetAgentTime(sec);
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

My Method:

```
public string GetAgentTime(double sec)
{
   TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec);
   return string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                        t.Hours,
                        t.Minutes,
                        t.Seconds
                       ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [TimeSpan.TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) but it returns a double so fix the format too:

```
return string.Format("{0:00}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s", t.TotalHours, 
                                                t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [t.TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx).  `t.Hours` is going to wrap once it hits a full day, and increment `t.Days` accordingly.

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional hours.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Define an interval of 1 day, 15+ hours.
      TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); 
      Console.WriteLine("Value of TimeSpan: {0}", interval);

      Console.WriteLine("{0:N5} hours, as follows:", interval.TotalHours);
      Console.WriteLine("   Hours:        {0,3}", 
                        interval.Days * 24 + interval.Hours);
      Console.WriteLine("   Minutes:      {0,3}", interval.Minutes);
      Console.WriteLine("   Seconds:      {0,3}", interval.Seconds);
      Console.WriteLine("   Milliseconds: {0,3}", interval.Milliseconds);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       Value of TimeSpan: 1.15:42:45.7500000 
//       39.71271 hours, as follows: 
//          Hours:         39 
//          Minutes:       42 
//          Seconds:       45 
//          Milliseconds: 750
```

Comment: I can.  There's also lots of examples in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TotalHours` property, which returns the entire value of the `TimeSpan` expressed in whole and fractional hours. You just need to truncate the value to get the whole hours:

```
public string GetAgentTime(double sec) {
  TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec);
  return string.Format(
    "{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
    Math.Floor(t.TotalHours),
    t.Minutes,
    t.Seconds
  ); 
}
```

Comment: @TheTruthIsInCode: That's strange... It should say that there is no `floor` method in `Math`, as it should be `Floor`. I corrected the code.

Comment: Ok. my mistake I didn't see the change to TotalHours...Now I get a format Exception: Format specifier was invalid.  We're getting close!

Answer (score -1):

Why bother with the `TimeSpan`? This is simpler and does exactly what you want:

```
public static string GetAgentTime( double s )
{
  int    seconds   = (int) Math.Round(s,0) ;
  int    hours     = Math.DivRem( seconds , 60*60 , out seconds ) ; // seconds/hour
  int    minutes   = Math.DivRem( seconds , 60    , out seconds ) ; // seconds/minute
  string agentTime = string.Format( "{0:00}h:{1:00}m:{2:00}s",
                       hours , minutes , seconds
                       ) ;
  return agentTime ;
}
```

Comment: This looks much more complicated to me.